# Sims 3: How can you maximize profits from fish?

Tags: the-sims-3, sims-3-ambitions

A detailed query for the statistically inclined!

If one of your household Sims is an Angler, how can you maximize profit from the fish?

I noticed at least 4 different ways fish can be sold, and I'm wondering whether cooking Angelfish, for example, can get profit somehow? ***[Question 1]*** **Can a good cook sell Perfect cooked meals at the consignment store or grocery store or some other way?**

It seems that the least profitable way to sell is the inventory selling of the "drag here to sell" functionality (method 1); but I'm wondering, ***[Question 2]*** **what is more profitable**: selling the fish raw at the consignment store (method 2), sending the fish first to get mounted then selling the mounted fish at the consignment store (method 3), or selling the fish raw at the grocery store (method 4), which *seems* that it could be the most profitable method, but that's a personal and not statistical impression?

I would be most impressed and grateful if you supplement your answer with ***[Question 3]*** **information that takes into account the *weight*, *type*** (Salmon, Shark, etc.) **and *quality*** (Excellent, Perfect, etc.) **of the fish**. For example, is the price of the mounted fish sold at the consignment store affected only by the weight of the fish regardless to quality, or does quality affect the price there too? Would a *mounted heavy Perfect shark* sell for more at the consignment store or sell for more if it is sold raw at the grocery store? Should I sell traditionally eaten fish, like Salmon, at the grocery store, and traditionally prized fish like trophy mounted sharks at the consigment store; or does the game not really go that deep and meaningful when it comes to numbers and profit?

Thank you.